# CSS animation lurching on startup

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I'd like to know how to smooth my animation when it first starts. At the moment each bubble lurches forward before transitioning into a smooth animation, but I don't want any noticeable lurching on startup.

I've tried the following:

- Adding a transition property to the bubble class
- Changing the animation-timing-function to ease-in
- Changing the duration of the animation to be longer

None of that worked and I'm not sure how to achieve this effect.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var bubbles = $('.bubble')

  function animate_bubbles() {
    bubbles.each(function(index) {
      $(this).css( 'animation-delay', `${index * 0.3}s` )
      $(this).addClass('bubble-active')
    })
  }

  animate_bubbles()

});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

#page-wrapper {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10%;
  background: black;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}


.bubble {
  background: skyblue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
}

.bubble:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
}


.bubble-active {
  animation: bubble-animation 3s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes bubble-animation {
  from { 
    transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(25%) rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(25%) rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='test.css'>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='page-wrapper'>
      <div class='bubble'></div>
      <div class='bubble'></div>
      <div class='bubble'></div>
      <div class='bubble'></div>
      <div class='bubble'></div>
      <div class='bubble'></div>
      <div class='bubble'></div>
      <div class='bubble'></div>
      <div class='bubble'></div>
      <div class='bubble'></div>
      <div class='bubble'></div>
      <div class='bubble'></div>
      <div class='bubble'></div>
      <div class='bubble'></div>
      <div class='bubble'></div>
      <div class='bubble'></div>
      <div class='bubble'></div>
      <div class='bubble'></div>
    </div>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='test.js'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are moving to the right like that because the start of the animation immediately tells the bubbles to `translateX(25%)`. If you load the page with the transform already applied, it works like you'd want. See the updated snippet below with just one extra line of CSS.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var bubbles = $('.bubble')

  function animate_bubbles() {
    bubbles.each(function(index) {
      $(this).css( 'animation-delay', `${index * 0.3}s` )
      $(this).addClass('bubble-active')
    })
  }

  animate_bubbles()

});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

#page-wrapper {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10%;
  background: black;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}


.bubble {
  background: skyblue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(25%) rotate(0deg);
}

.bubble:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
}


.bubble-active {
  animation: bubble-animation 3s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes bubble-animation {
  from { 
    transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(25%) rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(25%) rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='test.css'>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='page-wrapper'>
      <div class='bubble'></div>
      <div class='bubble'></div>
      <div class='bubble'></div>
      <div class='bubble'></div>
      <div class='bubble'></div>
      <div class='bubble'></div>
      <div class='bubble'></div>
      <div class='bubble'></div>
      <div class='bubble'></div>
      <div class='bubble'></div>
      <div class='bubble'></div>
      <div class='bubble'></div>
      <div class='bubble'></div>
      <div class='bubble'></div>
      <div class='bubble'></div>
      <div class='bubble'></div>
      <div class='bubble'></div>
      <div class='bubble'></div>
    </div>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='test.js'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is start and end the keyframes at a `translateX` of `0%`, add in extra keyframes to handle the actual animation. In the following example, I've added an extra keyframe point at `50%` that goes to a `translateX` offset of `25%`.

This results in a 'smooth' transition, but does cause the bubbles to stop briefly once returning to their original position. You may want to consider adding extra points in the keyframe animation, each with their own unique `translateX` offsets :)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var bubbles = $('.bubble')

  function animate_bubbles() {
    bubbles.each(function(index) {
      $(this).css('animation-delay', `${index * 0.3}s`)
      $(this).addClass('bubble-active')
    })
  }

  animate_bubbles()

});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#page-wrapper {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10%;
  background: black;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.bubble {
  background: skyblue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
}

.bubble:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
}

.bubble-active {
  animation: bubble-animation 3s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes bubble-animation {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(0%) rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(25%) rotate(-360deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(0%) rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8' />
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='test.css'>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='page-wrapper'>
    <div class='bubble'></div>
    <div class='bubble'></div>
    <div class='bubble'></div>
    <div class='bubble'></div>
    <div class='bubble'></div>
    <div class='bubble'></div>
    <div class='bubble'></div>
    <div class='bubble'></div>
    <div class='bubble'></div>
    <div class='bubble'></div>
    <div class='bubble'></div>
    <div class='bubble'></div>
    <div class='bubble'></div>
    <div class='bubble'></div>
    <div class='bubble'></div>
    <div class='bubble'></div>
    <div class='bubble'></div>
    <div class='bubble'></div>
  </div>
  <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src='test.js'></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope this helps! :)